# Phonegap jquerymobile href to server side html

Tags: hyperlink, cordova, href

IN a phonegap jquery mobile index.html that has an achor href to a server side (http://mywebsite.com/products.html  and NOT using rel=external). When that is clicked on and loaded, how do you ensure that the js files in your index.html still are accessible by the products.html.

It seems that when product.html is loaded, the .js files in index.html are not accessible.  I do not want to repeat all of them in the products.html.  What is the solution to this?   When running not in PhoneGap and in a browser, the .js script files in the index.html are still available seems like.

I am using the latest version of phonegap and Jquery mobile 1.3.0 and jquery 1.7.

Comment: even if u add them there will beno performance issue

Answer (score 0):

if you use jquery mobile using 
it is same like you use $.load
so your script and stylesheet in yoursite not load.
But if you place your script and css inside data-role="page" your js and css can be load..
For example

```
<body>
  <div data-role="page">
         your js file and css file place in here for can be load
  </div>
</body>
```